# Damselflies: which exact species of Coenagrion

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I recently took the following pictures of *Coenagrion* spp.(6th of June, in Versoix forest (small pond), Geneva area, Switzerland, Alt: ~450m).

Picture detailed & cropped:

[image: male-1]
[image: male-head]
[image: female-1]
[image: male-tail-female-head]

For the identification, I hesitate between two species:

- *Coenagrion pulchellum*
- *Coenagrion puella*

The male one seem to be *Coenagrion puella* while the female one has black patterning like a *Coenagrion pulchellum*.

I read in a book (`Les Libellules de France, Belgique, Luxembourg & Suisse` from *Jean-Pierre Boudot*, *Daniel Grand*, *Hansruedi Wildermuth* et *Christian Monnerat*) that the male *Coenagrion pulchellum* can have very similar field marks to male *Coenagrion puella* (for example the typical black U-shaped marking).

Which species are these — is it possible that the two species can crossbreed (male = *Coenagrion puella* and female = *Coenagrion pulchellum*) or are the female field marks a more reliable indicator of the species for both (male and female = *Coenagrion pulchellum* in this case)?

Comment: I corrected the formatting for the scientific names — if you are interested, this is [an introduction to scientific naming conventions](https://www.enago.com/academy/how-to-write-scientific-names-in-a-research-paper-animals-plants/) and these are the [complete "rules"](https://www.iczn.org/the-code/the-code-online/). I also edited your post for concision and clarity.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your edit, in fact I never know how to format latin names in SE sites (I often make a draft in an external text editor before), but for sure my question looks better now. Also, I am not a native English speaker, then thanks for the corrections/rephrasing :).